# Time series or Panel data

Tags: time-series, panel-data

I gathered data on my variables for a single country but for over a period of 10 years. Is that panel data or time series?

Comment: I believe you have a longitudinal sampling design so you’ll need to use a longitudinal model like a linear mixed effects model

Answer (score 2):

For each variable, the corresponding data values you collected for this **single country** form a *time series*. So what you have is a collection of time series for a single country.

If you had collected time series data on these same variables for **multiple countries** you would have *panel data*, that is, a collection of time series for multiple countries.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you suggest me which model I can use for my analysis as i'm doing a regression analysis.

Comment: I can't possibly suggest a model since I don't know anything about your study questions and data. You can post a new question on this forum where you can provide the specific details that would enable someone to answer your question.